# React Native image as string not found

Tags: ios, image, react-native

This works just fine:

```
<Image source={require('./imgs/animage.jpg')}></Image>
```

This returns an error:

```
var theimage = './imgs/animage.jpg';

<Image source={require(theimage)}></Image>
```

The error returned is:

"Requiring unknown module './imgs/animage.jpg'. If you are the module is there, try restarting the package"

Really no idea what the problem is.

This works:

```
var theimage = require('./imgs/animage.jpg');
```

But this still does not:

```
var theimage = 'animage';
var theimage = require('./imgs/' + theimage + '.jpg');
```

I can't see any way to produce images dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The new asset system (as well as the old require('image!xyz')) are for static images only. This is because all the images paths are figured out statically in the build step without the program being run. At this point the build system doesn't know about variables.

So you have to use

```
<Image source={{uri: theimage}}></Image>
```

But the URI can have folders. In order to always have your up-to-date resource folder compiled into the app during each build you need to create a **folder link** in your Xcode project not a group. A group only contains the files that are there at the time you create the group. A folder link reflects the actual content of that folder.
E.g. you have a folder somewhere in your project called *images*. In there is a folder *backgrounds* with a file *my_background.jpg*. You add *images* as folder reference to your project. Then you can use

```
{uri: 'images/backgrounds/my_background.jpg'}
```

Comment: So you're saying you choose to 'add files to <project>' and then select the folder with all the images in and then deselect to copy items over and change the folder tab to 'create folder reference' rather than the 'create groups' option?

Comment: The way that I usually do it though is to add the folder under "Build Phase" -> "Copy Bundle Resources". But it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible with the above coding for some reason. Here is one solution I found:

```
var theimage = 'animage.jpg';

<Image source={{uri: theimage}}></Image>
```

All the images have to be added to the xcode project. This way, their location can't be separated by folders however.

Comment: You have old information: image locations can be separated in folders and they don't have to be added to xcode project anymore. This change was made when Android support landed (I can't remember exact version number).

Comment: Well can you provide an answer to my original question then?

Comment: The code is correct, but the additional sentence "have to be added to the xcode project" isn't anymore true (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#source)

Comment: That's with 'require' and not 'uri'. With URI the path won't work correctly. But 'require' doesn't work with dynamic naming, like I described in the original question.